# having clause with case statement

Tags: sql, oracle, having

I'm trying to get row groupings that have a max date col4_date where col5 = Hi. I noticed that others have done similar queries with a case. Perhaps I need to use an in clause to do this. The max (col4_date) is where this is failing. Any advice would be nice

```
select  col1, col2, col3  from table1 t1 
group by col1, col2, col3
HAVING 
 sum(case when ( max (col4_date) =  col4_date ) and (col5 = 'Hi' )  then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

table 1 contents

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4_date | col5
-----+------+------+-----------+-----
D    | F    | G    | 4/3/2018  | Hi 
D    | F    | G    | 1/1/1970  | Bye
H    | I    | J    | 1/1/1970  | Hi 
H    | I    | J    | 4/3/2018  | Bye
```

output

```
col1 | col2 | col3
-----+------+-----
D    | F    | G
```

thanks for your help

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  It is really unclear what you want the logic to do.

Comment: table 1 contents

col1 col2 col3 col4_date col5
D    F    G    4/3/2018  Hi 
D    F    G    1/1/1970  Bye

H    I    J    1/1/1970  Hi 
H    I    J    4/3/2018  Bye 
output 
D    F    G

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't know why it doesn't allow for carriage returns

Comment: Do  **not** put sample data into comments. [edit] your question

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing as a sub-query works

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
  FROM grp
 WHERE     (col1, col2, col3, col4) IN (  SELECT col1,
                                                 col2,
                                                 col3,
                                                 MAX (col4)
                                            FROM grp
                                        GROUP BY col1, col2, col3)
       AND col5 = 'Hi';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Oracle's `KEEP LAST` to get the `col5` value for the last `col4_date`:

```
select col1, col2, col3
from table1
group by col1, col2, col3
having max(col5) keep (dense_rank last order by col4_date) = 'Hi';
```

Answer (score 1):

This applies a CASE to get your result:

```
select  col1, col2, col3
from table1 t1 
group by col1, col2, col3
HAVING -- compare overall max date and max date for 'Hi'
   max(col4_date) = max(case when col5 = 'Hi' then col4_date end)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you want

```
select  col1, col2, col3  
from table1 t1
join (select col1, col2, col3, max(col4_date) as max_col4_date
      from table1
      group by col1, col2, col3
) sub on sub.col1 = t1.col1 and sub.col2 = t1.col2 and sub.col3 = t1.col3 and sub.max_col4_date = t1.col4_date
where col5 = 'Hi'
```

Comment: That sub-query seems a bit strange. GROUP BY in wrong query?